Identification of the container executing portscans
I have a VM running a bunch of docker containers. The VM is behind a firewall running crowdsec. Every few days or so crowdsec bans the internal IP address of the VM because of multiple ports being scanned.
I want to figure out which container actually does the port scanning to check if this is a configuration error or a malicious activity.
What would be the easiest way to get the source IP address of the actual container which initializes the port scans?

Run tcpdump on the vm (tcpdump -nn -i any ...), replacing ... with a filter expression that will match ports in the port scan. This will show you the source address of the docker container, and you can figure out which container that is by looking for the matching address in docker container inspect.
